# My USA passport to France wasn’t stamped, can I re-enter?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, paperwork, france, passport-stamps

I’m American and recently bought a house in France. On July 17 I traveled from USA to France. On Oct 10 I returned to the USA (to make sure it was less than 90 days). Leaving France the border agent asked me when I last entered, and pointed out my last stamp was from February. I checked and this was true, but he believed I entered in July (which is true), and let me go. My question is, can I return to France before waiting three more months in the USA? Or is there electronic record I was there? We are waiting for my livret de famille but with COVID it might take months and I want to return to my husband and home.

Comment: With an exit stamp from 2020-10-10 (not meantioned in the question, but assumed to exist) and no corresponding entry stamp, they will assume you entered 90 days before leaving.

Comment: You should contact the French consulate and ask for a D-Visa to reenter. At present, US residents are not permitted to enter the Schengen Area for visiting purposes. Any D-Visa would override the 90 days rule.

Comment: Thanks Mark! They didn’t give me an exit stamp, either. For now I was allowed to enter since I’m married to a french man, but can’t stay longer than 90 days until I get my new visa (for which we are still waiting for our livret de famille)

Answer (score 1):

There's no electronic record, so indeed, if you never got an entry or exit stamp for a specific stay, then that stay essentially "never happened".

As such, you can safely return to France without delay, even with the COVID-19 restrictions since you're the spouse of a French citizen.

However, if arriving directly from the US, one normally needs a negative COVID-19 test taken within 72 hours of entry. Not sure whether being the spouse of a French citizen exempts you from that.

Comment: @phoog Ah, fairs. Thinking of how to edit the answer but am not sure atm

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115069/discussion-on-answer-by-crazydre-my-usa-passport-to-france-wasnt-stamped-can-i).